# What is the median of $y_{i}$ given $x_{i}$ for the function $y_i=\max\{0, x_{i}^{\prime}\beta + u_{i}\}$

Tags: regression, mathematical-statistics, linear-model, quantile-regression

$y_{i}$ is a kx1 matrix, $x_{i}$ is a kxk matrix, $\beta$ is a 1xk matrix of coefficients and $u_{i}$ is a kx1 matrix of error terms.

$y_i=\max\{0, x_{i}^{\prime}\beta + u_{i}\}$

and $med(u_{i}|x_{i})=0$

How do you do you find a conditional median of $y_{i}$ given $x_{i}$

I understand that this is a censored regression model and that $y_{i}$ has been censored at 0

$ y_{i} = \Bigg\{ \begin{array} { l l } { y^{*}_{i}}& {y^{*}_{i}>0} \\ { 0}&{y^{*}_{i} \leq 0 } \end{array}$

Where $y^{*}_{i} = x_{i}^{\prime}\beta + u_{i}$

But I don't know where to go from here.

Edit:

because there have been no assumptions made on the error term other than $med(u_{i}|x_{i})=0$ and previous sections of the question utilized quantile regression I think this may require that approach.

$med(y_{i}|x_{i}) = med(\max\{0, x_{i}^{\prime}\beta + u_{i}\}|x_{i})$

$Q_{y|x}(0.5|x_{i}) = Q_{\max\{0, x_{i}^{\prime}\beta + u_{i}\}|x}(0.5|x_{i})$

$= Q_{\max\{0, x_{i}^{\prime}\beta + u_{i}\}|x}(0.5|x_{i})$

$= \max\{Q_{x_{i}^{\prime}\beta}(0.5|x_{i}),0\} + \max\{Q_{u_{i}}(0.5|x_{i}),0\}$

$= \max\{med(x_{i}^{\prime}\beta|x_{i}),0\} + \max\{med(u_i|x_{i}),0\}$

because $med(u_{i}|x_{i})=0$

$= \max\{med(x_{i}^{\prime}\beta|x_{i}),0\}$

it seems to make sense to me but is that all technically sound?

Comment: (1) The censoring level is $0,$ not $y_i.$  (2) You don't have strong enough assumptions to deduce much at all: what  else can you assume about the full distribution of the $(u_i)$?

Comment: It doesn't say, but my guess is $u_{i}$ is normally distributed. If it is then the median and the mean would be the same. so then I think I would be able to then say that $E(u_{i}|x_{i})=0$

Comment: Ordinarily one might suppose the $u_i$ are iid Normal, but since the question refers explicitly only to the *median,* it strongly suggests it wants you to contemplate a far more general setting.  It's still probably ok to assume the $u_i$ are independent, because they are referred to individually rather than collectively, but that's about it.  Since you're guessing, would it be fair to assume this is a textbook problem?  And if so, what hints does the preceding material in the book supply about the intended meaning of this notation?